# Code help to prevent duplicate recording in wix database csv file upload

Tags: database, upload, duplicates, velo

Code help to prevent duplicate recording in wix database csv file upload.

I can't run the code below. Why?

Database: AmericanSamoa,
Check duplicate column : originalConnectionDetails

By checking the original link url address in the database, I want to prevent duplicate entries if the record was previously loaded with csv file.

[image]

My backend code

```
import wixData from 'wix-data';
import request from "request-promise";



export async function AmericanSamoa_beforeInsert(item, context) {

 if (item.originalConnectionDetails) {        
        item.originalConnectionDetails= await wixData.query('AmericanSamoa').ne('_id', 
item._id).startsWith('originalConnectionDetails', item.originalConnectionDetails).find().then((x) => 
{
 const total = x.totalCount;
 if (total > 0) {
 return `${item.originalConnectionDetails}-${total+1}`;
            } else {
 return item.originalConnectionDetails;
            }
        })
    }

 return item
}
```

Comment: Isn't there any answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution !

---This code prevents duplicate records (if they were written to the database before) during csv file upload.

However, it should not be possible to record repeatedly in the csv file you added. Because the first time uploaded does not check the duplicate records in the file. It checks the csv file in the database and uploaded.

Backend Code

```
import wixData from 'wix-data';

export function searchForDuplicates(value) {
 return wixData.query("Afghanistan")
   .eq("originalConnectionDetails", value)
   .find()
   .then((results) => {
 return results.items.length;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
 let errorMsg = err;
    });
}

export function Afghanistan_beforeInsert(item) {
 return searchForDuplicates(item.originalConnectionDetails).then((res) => {
 if(res > 0) {   
 return Promise.reject("Duplicate");
    }
 return item;
  });
}
```